# Access USB device from virtual machine (Windows 7 pro) while having host Linux (Debian 7)

Tags: linux, usb, virtual-machine, port

I am a bit at loss to find where the problem could be. I have a computer running Debian Wheezy. I want to run a microcontroller debugger from within a virtual machine (VMPlayer 6.03). I am using a USB BDM Multilink Rev. C which is pre-USB3 (if that have some influence as I only have USB3 ports on my computer).

With USB 1.1 or USB 2.0 on my VM settings, Windows recognise the device. But then when I try to launch the debugger, it complains that "Unable to open specified port". With USB3, Windows complains about missing drivers.

I have no problem to access a typical USB stick or a USB dongle.

On the host system, the device appears in lsusb. In dmesg, it seems to complain about "invalid maxpacket 256". I don't know if that have some influence. Otherwise I don't see much more information that seems relevant to me.

The host is running kernel 3.2.0-4-amd64, and the guest is a 32 bits machine.

For comparison, we ran the same VM on a different computer running Windows 7 and with the same USB device, and that ran with a setting of USB1.1.

I am not sure what to look for: should I try to fix this maxpacket thing? Is there a way Linux/Debian blocks some access to USB devices (iptables is fully cleared: everything allowed, even if that has probably nothing to do with it)? Could it be a problem of drivers, on the host the device is started with xhdi_hcd...

Can someone give me some hints?

Thanks.

Comment: Which one is the *specified port* which cannot be opened?

Comment: Well, on the IDE that I use (CodeWarrior) on the VM, I can select the port. It recognise it directly as "USB1: USB-ML-12-Rev C (PE5515899)". Then I get the error message indicated above. And it cannot find it again unless I leave the IDE, and disconnect/reconnect the USB device. The P55... is the serial number also recognised by Debian.

Comment: Have you tried running the debugger as a privileged user?

Comment: You mean running the VM as a root? That I haven't...

Comment: No, I just meant, from within the VM, to start the debugger as a privileged user.

Comment: Can I do that in Windows?

Comment: Yes you can. If you start the debugger by clicking on the icon, right-click on it, you will see an option: start as adminsitrative user, or some such thing. If you start it from terminal, open the while terminal as administrative user, by going to Programs -> terminal, then again right click on it.

Comment: Sorry for being slow. It does not help. It gives exactly the same error.